# Weird vertical line appearing between divs

Tags: html, css, forms, svg

I'm having some issues with an input I'm working on. It's a text input with an inline submit button. I added an SVG to the background of the button to give it the appearance of being cut out in a triangle (see image).

```
<div class="input-block animated fadeIn">
    <span class="sub">Have a 5-digit code? Enter it here.</span>
    <div id="code-input" class="ui action massive input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="X3FMN" maxlength="5">
            <button id="code-submit" class="ui icon button">
                <i class="mdi mdi-arrow-right"></i>
            </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: picture of input]

However, as you can see, there's a strange vertical line that's showing up. In web inspector, it appears that the line is contained in the input element and not the button element. I've tried tinkering with the CSS borders and outlines and forcing them off, but I've had no luck.

The line in question seems to be caused by this CSS rule:

```
.ui.action.input:not([class*="left action"]) > .button:last-child,    
.ui.action.input:not([class*="left action"]) > .buttons:last-child > 
.button, .ui.action.input:not([class*="left action"]) > .dropdown:last-child {
    border-radius: 0px 0.285714rem 0.285714rem 0px;
}
```

If it's deactivated, the line disappears, but so do the rounded corners at the right end of that element.

The site can be viewed at [healthdollars.com](http://healthdollars.com) (still in development).

**UPDATE:** It seems that the line appears in Chrome all the time and in Safari only when the input loses focus (both on OS X).

Comment: Add this line code: `-webkit-appearance: none;`

Comment: have you tried adding the following textarea {border-color:transparent;box-shadow: none;outline: none !important;}

Answer (score 2):

This rule...

```
.ui.action.input:not([class*="left action"]) > .button:last-child,
.ui.action.input:not([class*="left action"]) > .buttons:last-child > .button, 
.ui.action.input:not([class*="left action"]) > .dropdown:last-child {
    border-radius: 0px 0.285714rem 0.285714rem 0px;
}
```

... defines a `border-radius` to define the border shape around the green element with the arrow. Unfortunately, although there is *no* definition of a left border, this causes a minimal border to be drawn on the left side, which won't go away unless you erase the above rule, but this also makes the corners on the right side be without rounding, which you don't want.

I've tried adding and removing many settings, but the only little trick that works is adding `border-left: 1px solid #fff;` to the `<button>`tag with id `#code-submit` (directly in the HTML):

```
<button id="code-submit" class="ui icon button" style="border-left: 1px solid #fff;">
```

It creates a white left border which you don't see, since it joins the white background of both elements, and which replaces the light gray border that you wanted to get rid of.

This is not 100.0000% perfect, since, if you look *very* close, you can see a tiny (1px wide) white "interruption" at the upper and lower border where the code input field and the arrow image touch each other, but I couldn`t find anything better. I hope it helps you anyway...

Comment: I think you found the culprit, although I'm not sure why it's happening.  Another solution would be to remove the border-radius style on the input and button and put the border-radius on the containing div and set its overflow to hidden.

Comment: That does look like the issue. For me, adding the border seems to increase the size of the line, though. So odd. When I try adding a negative left margin, it decreases the line enough that I can live with it. I also tried removing the border radius with no luck.

Comment: could it be that you changed the `box-sizing` setting in the meanwhile? Because when I checked and tried different border widths, it didn't change the overall width of the element, IIRC. So I supposed it would be `border-box`...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, try the follow code:

```
header#home div.header-content div#code-input button#code-submit {
    background-color: #7BE13E;
    background-image: url("/img/triangle-white.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 75px;
    position: relative;
    background-position: left center;
    margin-left: -3px;
}
```